# Postgresql update each row with a random value

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is similar to other questions but it appears to vary on a database-by-database implementation. I am using postgres and things like `NEWID` do not appear to exist.

This is what I want to work:

```
update foo set bar = (select floor(random() * 10) + 1);
```

I understand *why* it doesn't but I can't seem to find a suitable solution that works for Postgres. I want the value of `bar` to be a random number between 1 and 10 that differs *per* row.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I think that Postgres might optimize the subquery.  Doesn't this work?

```
update foo
   set bar = floor(random() * 9 + 1);  -- from 1 to 10, inclusive
```

Comment: my take is to create a random function and use it. `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_between(low INT ,high INT) 
   RETURNS INT AS$$
BEGIN
   RETURN floor(random()* (high-low + 1) + low);
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql' STRICT;` Then use the function `update foo
   set bar = random_between(1,10)`

Comment: @Doogle: this is not required to `+1`

Answer (score 17):

```
update foo set bar = floor(random() * 10) + 1;
```

Comment: This was very helpful in anonymizing my accounts table's emails: `UPDATE accounts SET email = (select 'anonymized-' || (select floor(random() * 1000000) + 1 where accounts.id = accounts.id) || '@localhost')`

Comment: updated. there is no need in "where accounts.id = accounts.id". just call function directly. without 'select'.