# How to update column with sequential data?

Tags: postgresql, generate-series

I have table in Postgres

```
create table foo(bar int);
```

I know I can *insert* sequential data like this

```
insert into public.foo (select i from generate_series(1, 10) as i);
```

Now I want to update rows

```
update public.foo set bar = sq.t from (select t from generate_series(100, 10000) as t) as sq;
```

but this will update column to all the same values.
I know I need to use `where` somehow, but how can I use it without primary keys from both sides?

EDIT:
I will add more real life detail. I have complex table with around 20 columns. Around 40k rows. I am interested in two columns here, `pk` (or id, integer, with id_seq) and `created_date`.
I populated this table with duplicating initial 10 rows, so `created_date` are repeating (like `123123123`). I want to pick big range of dates from `generate_series` with 1 min interval and put them in `created_date` column to have sequential data there. And ideally regenerate ids from 1. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql update each row with a random value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463205/postgresql-update-each-row-with-a-random-value)

Comment: @Thirumal no, it does not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using window functions in an update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358613/using-window-functions-in-an-update-statement) or [Postgres UPDATE using rank window function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40296265/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, no, it does not

Comment: @IgorNikolaev Why not? It's exactly what you want to do. (Or do you really want to `generate_series()` again, and only update the first N rows or so?)

Comment: @Bergi because these solutions require subquery column to have pk for where clause and I don't have pk in` generate_series` subquery

Comment: @IgorNikolaev You do the subquery on the same table, and use its primary key ([or `ctid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40296406/1048572)). Don't use `generate_series()`, use a window function such as `row_number()`. Or why do you insist on using `generate_series()`?

Comment: @Bergi how is subquery on the same table? I need new sequence of values with arbitrary start and end

Comment: @IgorNikolaev And *which* values in the table do you want to update with the range between a start and an end value? What if there is a different number of rows than your range has entries?

Comment: @Bergi values of first and only column, if less, than put NULLs, if more, then cut redundant

Comment: @Bergi I really can't understand why it's so complicated, I have column with n values, I want Postgres to iterate over rows and clean values of this column and put there new values from previously evaluated `generate_series`. Is there something I don't get about relational databases?

Comment: @IgorNikolaev One important thing about relational databases is that rows don't have an order and not really an identity. If your table really has only a single column, you can achieve an equivalent result by just deleting all rows and then inserting your range (and, if necessary, the respective number of `NULL`s)

Comment: @Bergi I've edited the question with more real life details

Comment: @IgorNikolaev Do you care about the values in the other 18 columns, i.e. should the re-generated ids and dates have the same order as the original ones?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for

```
UPDATE foo
SET bar = CASE WHEN new_value < N THEN new_value + start END
FROM (
  SELECT
    ctid,
    row_number() OVER () as new_value
  FROM foo
) AS new_foo
WHERE foo.ctid = new_foo.ctid;
TABLE foo;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=50f063316511406a31b1212ccd70b6f1))</sup>

Comment: What is `ctid`?

Comment: @RTD It's a [system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) used to identify rows if you have no proper unique key